# How to determine if a specific radio button in a radio button group is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have a radio button group in my HTML form:

```
<form action="handler.php">
  <p><b>a or b or c</b></p>
  <p><input type="radio" id="abc" name="answer" value="a1">1<Br>
  <input type="radio" id="abc" name="answer" value="a2">2<Br>
  <input type="radio" id="abc" name="answer" value="a3">3</p>
 </form>
```

I want to check to see if a specific radio button (with value `a1`, for example) is checked, and then show a picture if it is:

```
<script>
function ShowPicture() {
  var word = document.getElementById("abc").value;

  if (word == "a1") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://picturesite.com/index" width="1024" height="720" align="left">';
  } 
}
</script>
```

How do I determine if the radio button is checked, so that I can use it in the condition used to display the image?

Comment: id need to be unique

Comment: Use a change event listener

Comment: How it looks like?

Comment: This isn't a tutorial service. If you don't know how javascript event listeners work then you need to study some beginner javascript tutorials

Answer (score 1):

This help you :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="handler.php">
              <p><b>a or b or c</b></p>
            <p><input type="radio" class="abc" name="answer" value="a1" onchange="ShowPicture()">1</p>
            <p><input type="radio" class="abc" name="answer" value="a2" onchange="ShowPicture()">2</p>
            <p><input type="radio" class="abc" name="answer" value="a3" onchange="ShowPicture()">3</p>
        </form>
        <div id="demo"></div>
        <script>
           function ShowPicture() {
              var word = document.getElementsByClassName("abc");
              var len = word.length;
               for(var i=0;i< len-1; i++) {
                   if(word[i].value == "a1" && word[i].checked)
                   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://picturesite.com/index" width="1024" height="720" align="left">'
                   
               }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! That`s cool! Is it possible somehow to create if statement? For example to connect two checkboxs statements? From different inputs?

Comment: you want show iframe if checkbox1 or checkbox2 is active?

Comment: Not at all. If i have for example 2 different checkboxes and if statement will connect them. For example, if a1 from first checkbox and b1 from another is active, then show picture

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

id must be unique ,so your code is not working ! But I have two methods to for your problem .First one is get by name and second is get by tagname .This two function are return a list of nodes so need to loop ...

```
//var word = document.getElementsByName("answer"); //get by name
 var word = document.getElementsByTagName("input");//get element name
 for(var i =0;i<word.length;i++){
  if(word[i].value == "a1") {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://picturesite.com/index" width="1024" height="720" align="left">';
  } 
}
```